# Using Actioncable and Rails 5 API mode together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, websocket, actioncable

I am creating a very basic chat app.  My goal is to have a Rails API backend and then build an IOS, Android, web, and desktop client. This is purely to explore Websockets and mobile development.

I've never used Actioncable, and my knowledge of Websockets is very limited.  What I'd like to know is if I can set up Actioncable on my Rails API and have it communicate with Node (for instance).

Does Actioncable act like any other Websocket?  Could I connect to it from my Node app through `ws://<host>/cable` and have a functional pub-sub system between whatever client and Rails?

I'm sorry if that doesn't make sense, I'm having a hard time wording it :)

Thank you!

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing right now.  Figure it out?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22669

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed you can!

1. Just like you create any api app, use generator

   ```
   rails new my_app --api
   ```
2. Create your_channel

   ```
   rails generate channel your_channel
   ```
3. Add mount path in `routes.rb`

   ```
   mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
   ```
4. Allow stream on subscribe method in `/app/channels/your_channel.rb`

   ```
   class YourChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel

     def subscribed
       stream_from 'messages'        #  <----- Stream Name Here
     end

     def unsubscribed
       # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
     end

   end
   ```
5. Call `ActionCable.server.broadcast` from any other part of your app to stream

   ```
   ActionCable.server.broadcast 'messages', message: 'ping'
   ```
6. Now use your front-end to test it. Since you told you want iOS Android and also mentioned about node, I assume you are using *(or would choose to use)* `react-native`

   ```
   import ActionCable from 'react-native-actioncable';
   const cable = ActionCable.createConsumer("ws://localhost:3000/cable");

   class YourReactClass extends React.Component {

       # add or update the following

       componentDidMount = () => {
           console.log("componentDidMount executed");
           this.subscription = cable.subscriptions.create("OrderChannel", {
               connected: function() { console.log("connected: action cable") },
                   disconnected: function() { console.log("disconnected: action cable") },
                   received: function (data) { console.log(data) }
               }
           )
       };

       componentWillUnmount () {
           this.subscription &&
           cable.subscriptions.remove(this.subscription)
       }

   }
   ```

And you're good to go, build your logic on top of this... If you got any problems, let me know.